# SQL Server connection with multiSubnetFailover fails, claims mirroring is enabled

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, windows, high-availability, availability-groups

I have two SQL Server instances in an availability group. They are not mirrored.

I'm trying to connect to the AG using the MS JDBC drivers (4.0) with a connection string including `multiSubnetFailover=true` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg558121.aspx)) and getting the following error:

> `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Connecting to a mirrored SQL Server instance using the multiSubnetFailover connection property is not supported. ClientConnectionId:<hex-id-string> errorCode[0] sqlState[08S01]`

It seems to think that mirroring is still enabled. Yet

- if I try `alter database d set partner off`, for example, it complains that the database is not configured for database mirroring.
- `select * from sys.database_mirroring` yields a row full of `NULL`s for every database.

Is there anywhere else that SQL Server might store some mirroring configuration, or some other way that it's getting confused?

---

Edit: Worth noting that without the `multiSubnetFailover` setting, this just works.

Comment: Did you make sure to run alter database d set partner off on both the primary and the mirror?  AG uses mirroring to keep the replica up to date but it doesn't play so well with mirroring.  What I have been doing is set up mirroring between the instances to get them in synch, remove it from both sides and then set up the AG.  I'm not sure about the multisubnet setting in JDBC.

Comment: Yes, I ran that on both sides, and both reported that they were already not configured for mirroring.

Comment: Has the database in question ever been mirrored? Is the AG listener configured for multi-subnet?

Comment: Yes, but mirroring was later removed. I'm interested in finding what remnants of that configuration there might be in places I haven't found yet. Yes the AG listener is configured for multi-subnet with a Windows failover cluster; it owns an IP address on both subnets.